# Google Drive API v3 : HTML Request

Tags: http, google-drive-api

Excuse my low level of English.
my question is about Google Drive API v3.
I use the WinDev language and I absolutely must send a request in HTML form: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q ......"
I have already managed to list files, folders, and download a file with this method.
I have 2 problems:

1. how to create the HTML request to create a folder?
2. how to create the HTML request to drop a file in the created folder?

thank you in advance for your help

I try :
"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q%20name=%27titi%27%20%2C%20mimeType=%27application/vnd.google-apps.folder%27

but it doesn't work/

Comment: About your 1st question of `how to create the HTML request to create a folder?`, in this case, I think that this official document will be useful. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create You can see the HTTP request at "Try this method". About your 2nd question of `how to create the HTML request to drop a file in the created folder?`, in this case, I think that this official document will be useful. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads If these were not useful, I apologize.

Comment: thank you for your reply
So I tried to create a folder with this:
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/create?name=%27lala%27%20%2C%20mimeType=%27application/vnd.google-apps.folder%27

But I got the following response:
{
"errors":
{
"code":404,
"message":"File not found: create.",
"errors":
[
{
"message":"File not found: create.",
"domain":"global",
"reason":"notFound",
"location":"fileId",
"locationType":"parameter"
}
]
}
}

Comment: This is a rest api.  You need to send post requests.

Comment: Thank you Linda for your response,
Yes I know I have to make a call to the API.
But in my WinDev language, I need the url which contains the address of the REST service + the parameters.
I can't make this url a String